# Only super class is initialized even though static field is referenced using sub type

Tags: java, static, initialization

I am doing some research on JAVA initialization process.
Here is a good material for reference:
[When a class is loaded and initialized in JVM](http://javarevisited.blogspot.hk/2012/07/when-class-loading-initialization-java-example.html)

On this page there is rule says:
*3) If Class initialization is triggered due to access of static field, only Class which has declared static field is initialized and it doesn't trigger initialization of super class or sub class even if static field is referenced by Type  of Sub Class, Sub Interface or by implementation class of interface.*

I really don't understand the idea. If the static field is referenced by Sub class, then this field of course need to create a sub class object or assigned by a Sub class object.
So, it definitely triggers Sub class initialization.

What's wrong with my interpretation?

---

*EDIT*:

1. It DOES trigger Super Class static initialization.
2. If the static field is final, and the static final field is initialized when declaring. Then it will neither load the class nor initialize the class, for this static final field is a compile time constant value. **Attention**: if the static final field is initialized in static block, then this statement does NOT hold anymore.

Comment: When you access a static field, the class associated with that gets Initialized. JVM doesn't look for which other classes refer this class and instantiate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the point is that in a situation like this:

```
public class Superclass {
    public static long INIT_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();

    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing Superclass");
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {
    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing Subclass");
    }
}
```

This code:

```
long time = Subclass.INIT_TIME;
```

is actually compiled to:

```
long time = Superclass.INIT_TIME;
```

and *only* "Initializing Superclass" will be printed, even though the source code referred to `Subclass`.

Comment: How could you figure out this example. I have spent hours to think over it. And failed. The block also says "it doesn't trigger initialization of super class or" Could you give another example of this?

Comment: @Zack: It means that if `Superclass` in this case has a non-Object superclass, then *that* won't be initialized either. EDIT: Except I've checked, and it *is* initialized, which is what I'd have expected. I think that part of the article is just wrong.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it yet. It really initialize the super class of the class where static field is defined.

Comment: @Zack: Indeed, and the way I read the specification, that's expected. I think *that* bit of the article is wrong, although the bit addressed in my answer is right.

Answer (score 0):

An example:

```
class A {
   public static int nA = 0;
}

class B extends A {
   public static int nB = 1;
}

class C extends B {
   public static int nC = 2;
}
```

Client:

```
int test = B.nA;
```

The JVM will initialize only Class A. Not B nor C.

Answer (score 0):

As shown above, when I run the Superclass/Subclass example, on calling Subclass.INIT_TIME,
both the Superclass and Subclass static initializers are getting invoked.

But here it is said that only "Initializing Superclass" will be printed.
Can someone clarify?