# Clarification on class initialization

Tags: java, classloader

A class initialization rule states that:
If Class initialization is triggered due to access of static field, only Class which has declared static field is initialized and it doesn't trigger initialization of super class or sub class even if static field is referenced by Type of Sub Class, Sub Interface or by implementation class of interface.
Then in the following code, "Initializing Superclass" only should be printed.

```
Superclass.java :

public class Superclass {

    public static long INIT_TIME = System.currentTimeMillis();

    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing Superclass");
    }
}

Subclass.java:

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing Subclass");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long time = Subclass.INIT_TIME;         
}
```

}

When I run this, output :

```
Initializing Superclass
Initializing Subclass
```

Comment: Where did you find that _rule_?

Comment: And what are you running?

Comment: The parent class will be initialized if you just *run* the child class.

Comment: The code you've written *does* only initializer `Superclass`. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Is the `main` method part of `Subclass`?

Comment: Got the point. When I run the main as part of subclass, both are initialised. But when I run main as part of a separate class, only superclass initi.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the[Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) in chapter 12.1.3.

The rule is: 
"If class Test has another class Super as its superclass, then Super must be initialized before Test."

Subclasses are not initialized, but of superclasses are.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your code is like this :

```
public class Temp extends SuperTemp {  // subclass

    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing Temp");
    }

}

class SuperTemp {        // super class
    static int i = 0;
    static {
        System.out.println("Initializing SuperTemp");
    }

}

class SomeOtherClass {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Temp.i); // from some other class you are calling SubClass.superClassField
    }
}
```

O/P :

```
Initializing SuperTemp
0
```

The reason : During Runtime `Temp.i` will be resolved to `SuperTemp.i` by the JVM. So, `Temp` will be *loaded* but not *initialized*. Looking at the way classes are loaded :

O/P of `java -verbose:class`

```
[Loaded SomeOtherClass from file XXXX]
[Loaded SuperTemp from file XXXX]
[Loaded Temp from file XXXX]
Initializing SuperTemp
0
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stated :-

> > If Class initialization is triggered due to access of static field, only Class which has declared static field is initialized and it doesn't trigger initialization of super class or sub class even if static field is referenced by Type of Sub Class, Sub Interface or by implementation class of interface

This clearly states that the output should be `Initializing Superclass` only.

I ran your program and get the output as

> Initializing Superclass
>
> 1414998665110

If you are getting output as you mentioned there is something else you are doing not stated in your question.

Note:- Referring to the answer provided by Jon Skeet on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16304733/only-super-class-is-initialized-even-though-static-field-is-referenced-using-sub) , it seems that one part of the aricle is wrong where it says:-

> If Class initialization is triggered due to access of static field, only Class which has declared static field is initialized and it doesn't trigger initialization of super class

This is not related to your case , since `INIT_TIME` is part of `Superclass`, hence you are basically writing `SuperClass_object.INIT_TIME` when you say `subclass.INIT_TIME`. If you had `INIT_TIME` field in your `Subclass` instead of `Superclass` you would get output :-

> Initializing Superclass
>
> Initializing Subclass
>
> 1414998665110

To summarize this means `Superclass gets intialized even if Class initialization is triggered due to access of static field, But Subclass is not initialized.`

Comment: Non-normative reference. -1

Comment: Removed it, had added it because someone specified in the comments as where did you get that rule ?

Comment: It means that the what user has posted in the question will not give the output as he stated, it will only print `Initializing Superclass`. not both `Initializing Superclass` and `Initializing Subclass`. Also a part of article is wrong which says even superclass will not be loaded if class intialization  is triggered due to access of static field.

Comment: But when I run the code as shown in the question, both the static blocks are executed even though the field is defined in the Superclass. Is there any gap that Im not able to detect?

Comment: Yes that can be the case when you are writing your `main()` method inside the `Subclass`, then you will get the output you are getting. Are you writing your `main()` method in a separate class ?